# Replacing the comma with a colon in a 2D list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a 2D list from a pandas table and have been trying to convert/replace the comma with a colon. I want to use this list so that I can use it in a dictionary to change the column headings in another dataframe. I'm happy for this to be turned into a string if need be.

ie :

`[['ASAP', 'As soon as possible'], ['AM', 'Before Midday'], ['PM', 'After Midday'], ['DOB', 'Date of Birth']]`

to

`'ASAP': 'As soon as possible',  'AM': 'Before Midday', 'PM': 'After Midday', 'DOB': 'Date of Birth'`

I am also thinking of replacing the spaces with _, but not decided on that yet. Would I do that the same way as I would to change the colon?

Many Thanks,

Raihan

I have tried .replace, tried to turn it into a string and then replace, also tried .join which removes the comma but also the quotation marks.

Comment: If you want to make a dictionary, no need to use string manipulation to add colons. Simply `my_dict = dict(my_2d_list)`

Comment: how did you get the list originally? if it's from a form like `pandas.DataFrame.to_list()`, there's also a `to_dict()` method

Comment: @ti7 yes I used to_list(). Feeling pretty silly now that I've spent the last few hours on this when there were a lot simpler solutons lol

Comment: don't feel silly - there are a huge number of Pandas methods and you've probably stumbled into an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! go ahead and Answer your own Question with what happened and what you did!

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help you also added output for clearance.

```
 preq = [['ASAP', 'As soon as possible'], ['AM', 'Before Midday'], ['PM', 'After Midday'], ['DOB', 'Date of Birth']]
    dictionary = ', '.join([f"'{key}': '{value}'" for key, value in preq])
    dictionary = dictionary.replace(' ', '_')
    
    print(dictionary)
```

[image: output]